# Layout FXML tournament project

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have a school project to do  :

A desktop application who manage tennis table tournaments.
We must use JavaFX whith Eclipse neo 3.0 IDE.

Here is the layout that i made on AI :

[image: tournament layout]

I know it's ugly but we don't get extra points for design..

I'm trying now to replicate it on JavaFX scene builder :

[image: scene builder layout]

The idea was coloring the route of the winning team.

I'm now asking some help here in order to get some advices on the way i choose to do it and the faisability of merging the rectangles.

Thanks

Comment: You could look into using a `Path`, `Polyline`, or `Polygon` rather than multiple `Rectangle`s. You may still need more than one if you want to be able to color the victor's path separately. If you remove the strokes you won't have those black borders clearly separating the different shapes. Also remove the rounded corners if you keep using the `Rectangle`s.

Comment: Just hope that the text doesn't get any longer/you're ok with ellipsis; The rectangles won't move/resize them based on the text size in the bottom-most `HBox`... BTW: I do not recommend using SceneBuilder for this purpose. The general structure of the scene is simple enough and using fxmls like this will result in a lot of boilerplate code, not to mention getting all the `fx:id`s for the `Rectangle`s right...

Comment: @Slaw @fabian : Thank both of you for your advices. I'll take a look at `Path` `Polyline` and `Polygon` elements.